# What is this word written on my t-shirt

Tags: word-meaning

What is this word written on my t-shirt and what does it mean?

[image: t-shirt]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Weather Vane:

> It says **Observed**. Please see [observe](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/observe). The rv and the ed are joined with [cursive script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursive).

The definition of observed is:

> notice or perceive (something) and register it as being significant.

For example:

> I observed you sleeping late yesterday, which is quite unusual.

Comment: And the "s" is difficult to read. But yeah, running the "r" and the "v" together makes it look like "Obsewed", which to the best of my knowledge is not an English word.